# php session cookie doen't start on localhost but working online

Tags: php, session, localhost, session-cookies

Recently my php session cookie stopped working on localhost but when i upload the same file online it works very fine i don't know what i have done wrong.

Here is my code to start a session on login.

```
<?php
define('sessionservername', '.example.com'); 
$Lifetime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; //31536000; // set cookie life time
$sessionTime = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60;
ini_set("session.gc_maxlifetime", $Lifetime);
ini_set("session.cookie_lifetime", $Lifetime); 
ini_set("session.gc_divisor", "1");
ini_set("session.gc_probability", "1");
    function sec_session_start(){
        session_name();
        $secure = false;
        $httponly = false; /*This stops JavaScript being able to access the session id */
            // Forces sessions to only use cookies.
        if (ini_set('session.use_only_cookies', 1) === false) { header("Location: login.php?err=Could not initiate a safe session");exit();}
        $cookieTimeer = 365 * 24 * 60 * 60; //31536000;
        $cookieParams = session_get_cookie_params();
        session_set_cookie_params($cookieTimeer, $cookieParams["path"], '.example.com', $secure, $httponly);
        session_start(); 
    }
    ?>
```

Thank on every page i added this line

```
<?php
session_set_cookie_params($sessionTime, "/", sessionservername, $sessionsecure, $sessionhttponly);
session_start();
?>
```

Comment: Huh... cookie stopped working? What does that mean?

Comment: @bub, i mean that my session doesn't start again on localhost

Answer (score 1):

Try removing this line or do not execute the line for localhost -

```
session_set_cookie_params($cookieTimeer, $cookieParams["path"], '.example.com', $secure, $httponly);
```

Above line sets to save cookie for the given domain only.

Comment: Thank you for posting an answer to my question, i have solved the problem by removing this function `sec_session_start()`